# running android application in background

Tags: android

in my application when I click on exit button the application has to run in background or my hme screen must be visible
how do i do this
i am new to android i have no idea about it

Comment: please post your question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an android *service*. Please read [this introduction](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html), and paticulary the part about the different kinds of application component.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your application run in the background, you need to create a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). You can read a short tutorial [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx). Be advised that there are battery concerns for having an application run all the time, so only do it if you absolutely need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service to handle the core logic of your app, and put a notification icon on the status bar. When the user check out the notification, you can display your UI and get logic data from your Service.